# How do I make a cell say "TRUE" if there are two or more values (any value) in the column?

Tags: excel

How do I make a cell say "TRUE" if there are two or more values (any value) in the column, when the rest of the column is blanks, but display "FALSE" if there is one or no values?

In my spreadsheet, I have the results of tests for different producers on different days. Each producer is a column and each day is a row. Not every producer is tested every day, so there are several blanks. Each producer needs to be tested twice a month. I would like a row on the top of the spreadsheet that displays "TRUE" if there are two values in the column, and "FALSE" if there are not two values in the column. It doesn't matter what the values are, but if it makes it easier, they always end in a 0. I know `=ISREF` will show if there is any value, but I specifically need to know if there are two or more values.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your attempted VBA code or state an explicit question.

Comment: The only code I've been able to find that's close is =ISREF. Explicit: How do I make a cell say "TRUE" if there are two or more values (any value) in the column, when the rest of the column is blanks, but display "FALSE" if there is one or no values?

Comment: ISREF isn't VBA, it's a cell formula.  Are you looking for a formula or actual VBA code?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to make a cell display "TRUE" if the column in question contains two or more values, but not less than two values. I don't care how it happens.

Comment: then Josh's answer will probably work for you.  This is a great place to get answers, but understand that it's all voluntary and most of us don't want to waste time trying to understand what the author is trying to ask.  Don't forget to give him credit and "check" his answer.

Comment: Volunteer or not, no need to be a jerk. I asked an explicit question when prompted. If you didn't want to waste time trying to figure out what I meant, then you didn't have to.

Comment: Apologies, my wording was poor.  I'm not saying you `are` wasting my time, but your question gives off the initial impression that you only want an answer without putting effort into it.  My comments are geared towards improving your question so more people will look at it yielding you the best chance at a excellent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=IF(COUNTA(R[2]C:R[6]C) >=2,"True","False")

COUNTA() counts the number of non-blank cells in a given range...
I am using R1C1 so your will probably look like

=IF(COUNTA(B2:B32) >=2,"True","False")